# How to have default and remove class on Ul li using vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener, queryselector

I have two ul with the same class, the concept I tried to achieve is when clicking the active li should have border color change. I have succeeded in that, the concept I need is I want to have the default same border color present on first ul li, and if I click other it should get removed and color should apply on clicked one. The code I have tried so far.

Any help will be appreciated !!

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.random-value li');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
        if (selectedEl) {

            selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("selected");

    }, false);
};
```

```css
.random-value li{
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        border: 1px solid green;
        padding: 15px 26px;
    }
    .random-value .selected{
     border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="first" class="random-value">
<li>200 </li>
<li>2010 </li>
<li>2100 </li>
<li>2030 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems to work.

Comment: I want first one to be default selected, ex 185 should have border color red and after that my current scenario should happen.

Comment: add `class="selected"` to the first `li` in your html then run the same code and if I understand the question correctly it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```js
//Making first option as Highlighted
document.querySelectorAll('.random-value li')[0].classList.add("selected"); 

var x = document.querySelectorAll('.random-value li');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
        if (selectedEl) {

            selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
        }
        this.classList.add("selected");

    }, false);
};
```

```css
.random-value li{
        margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        border: 1px solid green;
        padding: 15px 26px;
    }
    .random-value .selected{
     border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<ul id="first" class="random-value">
<li>200 </li>
<li>2010 </li>
<li>2100 </li>
<li>2030 </li>
</ul>
```